# Generate random values

Tags: ruby, faker

I want to generate random name using the following code:

```
def random_card_holder
  Faker::Name.first_name + " " + Faker::Name.last_name
end
```

But I get validation error. Is this code valid?

Comment: add more details about your validation and the error.

Comment: _"But I get validation error. Is this code valid?"_ – That's not a contradiction. Validations don't validate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this code valid?

Yes this is a valid code.

> But I get validation error.

You validate the (assumably) `card_holder` column, and the result of this ***valid*** code does not meet the validation rules.